# nested GROUP BY on several tables in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

My data is shaped hierarchically, like so: A->oneToMany->B->oneToMany->C

EDIT: By @akina 's request

```sql
CREATE TABLE a
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY;

CREATE TABLE b
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
aid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES a (`id`);

CREATE TABLE c
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
bid INTEGER FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES b (`id`);
```

TABLE A:

| AID |
| --- |
| 0 |

TABLE B:

| ID | AID |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |

TABLE C:

| ID | BID |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |

I want to convert it to a JSON for each A, something like

```json
{
 'aid': 0,
 'bs': [
   {
     'bid': 0,
     'cs': [
       {
         'cid': 0
       },
       {
         'cid': 1
       }
     ]
   },
   {
     'bid': 1,
     'cs': [
       {
         'cid': 2
       },
       {
         'cid': 3
       }
     ]
   }
 ]
}
```

A select clause would like so:

```
json_object(
  'aid', a.id,
  'bs', json_arrayagg(
    json_object(
      'bid', b.id,
      'cs', json_arrayagg(
        json_object('cid', c.id)
      )
    )
  )
)
```

unfortunately, I am not sure how to nest `GROUP BY`s for two nested json_arrayagg functions.

Doing `GROUP BY a.id, b.id` creates only one level of groups, where a.id and b.id are equal, effectively grouping by b.id only.

I also tried breaking the join like so:

```
select json_object(
  'aid', a.id,
  'bs', json_arrayagg(
    bjsons.bjson
  )
)
from a left outer join (
  ( select b.aid as aid, json_object(
      'bid', b.id,
      'cs', json_arrayagg(
        json_object('cid', c.id)
      ) as bjson
    from b left outer join c on c.bid = b.id
    group by b.id
  ) as bjsons on bjsons.aid = a.id
group by a.id
where a.id = 25
```

While this returns the right data, mysql first resolves the inner table creating bjsons for **ALL** `b`s, and then only joining the ones relevent to `aid=25`. This is wasteful and too expensive, and takes minutes to compute.

What other approach can I take?

Comment: *My data is shaped hierarchically, like so: A->oneToMany->B->oneToMany->C* Provide CREATE TABLE + INSERT INTO with some sample data and desired output for this data.

Comment: *EDIT: By @akina 's request* I see neither CREATE TABLE nor INSERT INTO script.

Comment: @Akina I thought it would be understandable without a DDL, but here it is. Desired output is provided, and i showed data contents as a table in lieu of INSERT INTO